# How do I replace text in an EJS template on hovering with a variable sent from a node js controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ejs

I have the following code snippet in my EJS file (as part of a node application).

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) { %>
    <li><%= documents[i] %></li>
    <h4 hidden> <%= my_dict[documents[i]] %></h4>

<% } %>



<script>
    $('li').hover(
        function () {
            const doc_text = $('.plain').text()
            const doc_mapping = my_dict[doc_text]
            $(this).replaceWith(doc_mapping);
        }
    );
</script>
```

Here, `my_dict` is a dictionary and `documents` is an Array which is passed from my node js controller

I basically need to replace the text of each `<li>` tag in the loop with the text `my_dict[text]` on hovering. I tried to do so using the above script but it isn't working. I also tried to include the text in a `<h4>` tag which is kept hidden and use it to replace the text.
But every time I hover over the text in the `<li>` tag, it gets replaced by all the text in all the  tags of the loop. Probably because I am not able to map each `<li>` uniquely to each `<h4>` tag.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand well your problem,  here is a simple solution.

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) { %>
    <li onmouseenter="hover(this, '<%= my_dict[documents[i]] %>')" onmouseleave="hover(this, '<%= documents[i] %>')"><%= documents[i] %></li>
    <h4 hidden> <%= my_dict[documents[i]] %></h4>
<% } %>

<script>
function hover(el, str) {
    el.innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
```